# Por que devemos importar MessageBox explicitamente no Tkinter mesmo importando com o asterisco?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Sempre que vejo programas utilizando `tkinter` e `messagebox` vejo as duas seguintes linhas no início do código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Se ao usarmos `from tkinter import *` importamos toda a biblioteca do `tkinter`, por que a necessidade de chamar a função `messagebox` a parte?

Comment: Na verdade, você _não_ _deve_ importar com "*" pra começar. 
Para evitar digitar "tkinter.' toda hora você pode: importar explicitamente o que for usar, ou, fazer `import tkinter as tk`  (nesse segundo caso, o messagebox, que é um submodulo, ainda precisa ser importado explicitamente)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso porque diferente do que alguns pensam o asterisco não importa **tudo** necessariamente.

Quando você faz:

```
from X import *
```

Se `X` for um módulo, o interpretador irá buscar por `X.__all__`, se `X` for um pacote, irá buscar por `X.__init__.__all__`. Se esse objeto existir, ele definirá o que será importado quando utilizado o asterisco. Só será importado tudo quando o `__all__` não estiver definido.

- [6.4.1. Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Por exemplo, se criarmos um módulo chamado `foo.py`:

```
# foo.py

__all__ = ['foonction']

def foonction():
    pass

def barction():
    pass
```

E em outro arquivo fizermos:

```
from foo import *
```

Teremos no nosso escopo atual a importação de `foo.foonction`, mas não de `foo.barction`. Para importar a função `barction` precisamos fazer isso explicitamente:

```
from foo import barction
```

É exatamente isso que ocorre com `tkinter.messagebox`. Por decisão dos desenvolvedores optaram por não expor `messagebox` no `__all__`.

E eu preciso discordar do que foi posto na outra resposta:

> De um modo geral, você nunca deve importar `*` mesmo assim.

Essa informação não é necessariamente errada, mas é necessariamente incompleta. Se você não pudesse importar utilizando o asterisco essa opção nem existiria na linguagem. Afinal, por que criarem algo que não pode usar? A questão é usar quando saber o que está fazendo; se você está ciente do que a importação faz, use sem medo.

Mas isso é maior do que a importação de módulos, somente faça aquilo que sabe o que está fazendo e nunca use algo sem entender - estando você importando um módulo do Python ou fazendo qualquer outra coisa em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Entendi. Basicamente então foi por decisão de quem desenvolveu.

Comment: Exatamente. Bela resposta. +1

Answer (score 4):

Assim como essa [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435558/9671639), a importação do `from tkinter import messagebox` é necessária simplesmente pela maneira como o pacote foi projetado para funcionar.

O autor do `tkinter` decidiu que importar "*" não importaria `messagebox`, ou alguns dos outros pacotes (`ttk` é outro exemplo)

PS: De um modo geral, você não deve importar `"*"` mesmo assim.