# Importação de bibliotecas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Há algum tempo tive uma dúvida sobre importação de bibliotecas (aqui: [Por que devemos importar MessageBox explicitamente no Tkinter mesmo importando com o asterisco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356896/por-que-devemos-importar-messagebox-explicitamente-no-tkinter-mesmo-importando-c)) e me explicaram que, naquele caso específico, importar utilizando `from <module> import *` não funcionaria.

Hoje estou novamente com a mesma dúvida, estudando alguns programas aqui me deparei com a seguinte forma de importação de bibliotecas:

```
from math import ceil
from math import sqrt
```

Ora, não seria mais fácil simplesmente utilizar:

```
from math import *
```

Neste caso, diferente do citado na minha outra pergunta, utilizar `from math import *` importaria o `ceil()` e também o `sqrt()` de uma só vez.

Então pergunto: Existe alguma vantagem em importar somente as duas funções específicas que se vai utilizar ao invés de importar toda a biblioteca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas vantagens, sim.

1. Não polui o escopo local;

Uma das grandes vantagens de se modularizar o código é separar as coisas em escopos distintos, assim você tem a liberdade para trabalhar no seu projeto sem se preocupar com conflito entre os nomes das funções. Ao importar com `from <module> import *` você estará importando tudo o que está declarado em `__all__` do módulo ou tudo caso o módulo não defina essa estrutura e, portanto, desta forma você não possui controle sobre o seu próprio escopo, o que é terrível.

2. O código não fica mágico;

Embora no Python muita coisa parece ser simples como passo de mágica, nesse ponto não é interessante. Como comentado no item (1), ao fazer `from <module> import *` você não possui controle sobre o escopo, então você não consegue saber o que está declarado. A consequência disso é que ao ler o código você pode ler algo como:

```
from A import *
from B import *
from C import *

...
x = get_answer()  # 42
```

E então, onde foi definida a função `get_answer`? Você pode até ir atrás da documentação dos módulos A, B e C, mas olha o recurso que precisa investir nisso apenas para saber de onde vem a função, enquanto `from C import get_answer` elimina qualquer obscuridade do código.

3. IDEs agradecem;

Da mesma forma que em (2) você sofrerá para determinar onde foi definida a função, a IDE, considerando que ela possui as ferramentas, também sofrerá para entender onde foi definida. Em muitos casos ela nem conseguirá resolver o escopo quando feito `from <module> import *`, então toda função ou variável que utilizar do módulo a IDE não conseguirá aferir se existe de fato, se a chamada da função condiz com a assinatura da mesma, etc. Provavelmente ferramentas que verificam a tipagem, como o MyPy, também sofrerão com isso.

Além disso, você não precisa duplicar a linha; você pode incluir mais de uma estrutura com o mesmo `import`:

```
from math import ceil, sqrt
```

Answer (score 1):

Vantagem seria o resultado final em tamanho e carregamento.

Exemplo quando vc importa `ceil` e `sqrt`, va vai gerar apenas esses pacotes,
caso uso o `*` vai importa toda a biblioteca(nem sempre depende da biblioteca) do `math`.

Mas isso pode depender da IDE tambem, pq algumas IDEs ja fazem esse processo de "remocao" onde somente os pacotes que estao sendo usados ou referenciados sao gerados na build, removendo todo o "lixo" que nao 'e usado.