# Problemas com código python

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estou praticando tkinter e o que eu quero é criar um botão onde o usuário escolhe uma imagem e então passar essa imagem para executar uma outra função com opencv.

Mas ao executar o código, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: select_image() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

aqui está o código completo:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.janela = Frame(master)
        self.janela.pack()

        self.btn = Button(self.janela, text="Selecione uma Imagem", command=self.select_image)
        self.btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    def select_image():
        path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        if len(path) > 0:
            image = cv2.imread(path)

            return(path)

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esqueceu de colocar o parâmetro `self` na assinatura do método `select_image`.

Comment: Mas aí deu outro erro: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Software Project\ProjectRobot\ProjectRobot\ProjectRobot.py", line 14, in select_image
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined

Comment: Funcionou.. esse também era um erro. O outro eu acabei encontrando. Muito obrigado :D

Comment: Sem problema, eu estava na escola então não pude ver seu outro erro, desculpa ;)

Answer (score 3):

Acabei encontrando, o erro era que precisava importar o método "filedialog".

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

só não sei porque precisou disso, porque "from tkinter import *" já não foi o suficiente.

Comment: Explico isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356896/5878

Comment: Muito útil explicação. Obrigado Anderson ^^